# How to hide user name and password in pip.log?

Tags: python, pip

I'm using pip to install Python libraries on VMs that are accessible to several users. Some of the libraries are stored on a private artifactory. To make pip able to access this private artifactory, I give appropriate username and password.

If there is an error while trying to access the artifactory, a file pip.log is automatically created. The following line is part of it:

```
Cannot fetch index base URL https://user:password!@artifactory.../
```

How could I prevent pip from writing user id and password in this log file?

Comment: There is [an open bug](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4746) about it.

Comment: I just found this: https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/5952 .  It appears that you can use keyring with pip, but I can't find any usage documentation.

Answer (score 5):

I can't find documentation for it, but pip supports [.netrc files](https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl-netrc.html) in `~` and `.`:

```
machine artifactory.hostname
login username
password password
```

These credentials should not show up in logs.

Comment: This solution works well on my machine. Nevertheless, when the "pip install" is run in a docker, I'm asked for login and password as if file ~/.netrc was not taken into account. Would you, by any chance, know what could make the difference?

Comment: Differing Python or pip versions could be the issue or maybe you placed .netrc in the wrong users home dir.

Comment: In case it matter - this feature was added in pip 9.0.0 per the [release notes](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#id37).

Answer (score 0):

Since October 2018, a [pull request](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/5773) was merged to hide basic-auth usernames and passwords in URLs, so this should not be an issue anymore, and just doing what you did should now not expose them in logs, etc.